# How do I convert my objects to an array in node.js?

Tags: node.js

When I execute the code below in node, the command prompt complains that it needs an array of objects in order to use objects-to-csv.

```
const ObjectsToCsv = require("objects-to-csv");

async function scrapeDescription(url, page) {
//more code ...
return {url, cats, main_img, name, descript, price};
}

async function saveDataToCsv(data) {
  const csv = new ObjectsToCsv(data);
  await csv.toDisk("spreadsheets/output.csv");
}

browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false}); 
const descriptionPage = await browser.newPage();
for (var i=0; i< 2; i++){
 result = await scrapeDescription(scrapeResults[i], descriptionPage);
 console.log(result);
}
await saveDataToCsv(result);
```

When I don't use the saveDataToCsv(data) function, I get the following results:

```
{
  url: 'https://www.example.com/product_info.php?products_id=479684',
  cats: 'JEWELRY < ANKLET < FASHION < ',
  main_img: 'images/20200312/AK001501.jpg',
  name: 'Faceted Bead Pearl Link Anklet',
  descript: ' Style No : 479684 Color : Multi Theme : Pearl  Size : 0.2"H, 9" + 3" L  One Side Only Lead and Nickel Compliant Faceted Bead Pearl Link Anklet',
  price: '$2.25 / pc'
}
{
  url: 'https://www.example.com/product_info.php?products_id=479682',
  cats: 'JEWELRY < ANKLET < FASHION < ',
  main_img: 'images/20200312/AK0001.jpg',
  name: 'Freshwater Pearl Disc Beaded Anklet',
  descript: ' Style No : 479682 Color : Neutral Theme : Pearl  Size : 0.25"H, 9" + 3" L  One Side Only Lead and Nickel Compliant Freshwater Pearl Disc Beaded Anklet',
  price: '$3.75 / pc$40.50 / dz'
}
```

So what I get is a couple of objects and I want to convert them to an array so that I can use objects-to-csv.

Comment: make an array and then just add `result` to it?

Answer (score 1):

I would change

```
for (var i=0; i< 2; i++){
    result = await scrapeDescription(scrapeResults[i], descriptionPage);
    console.log(result);
}
await saveDataToCsv(result);
```

to

```
let arr = [];
for (var i=0; i< 2; i++){
    result = await scrapeDescription(scrapeResults[i], descriptionPage);
    arr.push(result);
    console.log(result);
}
await saveDataToCsv(arr);
```

That way, you'll get all of your scraped objects in an array.
Let me know if that does it.

Answer (score 0):

This question was solved at a different forum. The trick was to use the spread operator inside of the for loop. resultsArray = [...resultsArray,result];

Comment: That's just a more expensive version of `resultsArray.push(result)`. The outcome in both cases is that you add an item to the array. Using the spread operator, however, you'd be creating new arrays every iteration, instead of literally using an array as it's supposed to be used in these cases and simply adding to it. I'd steer clear of that other forum's advice in the future.

Comment: I had tried using push already and it didn't work with result because result is a function.

Comment: 1. The result of `push` is *not* a function. It's a number - the new length of the array. 2. You don't *need* the result of `.push`. You just need to do `array.push(value)` and you'd get `value` inside `array`. It mutates the array in-place. So, either you didn't use `push` properly or there is something you're not showing in that example which is relevant.